# Second derivative peculiarity: Black-Scholes

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

This is the function for a call option

```
bsm=1/2 At E^(-q τ)
   Erfc[-(((-q + η + σ^2/2) τ + Log[At/K])/(
    Sqrt[2] σ Sqrt[τ]))] - 
 1/2 E^(-η τ)
   K Erfc[(σ Sqrt[τ] - ((-q + η + σ^2/
        2) τ + Log[At/K])/(σ Sqrt[τ]))/Sqrt[2]]
```

I've checked this against MMA's `FinancialDerivative` and the price and greeks match.

Now according to theory the second derivative of `bsm` wrt `K` should give a density (after some adjustments, see `spd`).

The only way I've seen this claim that dcdkk returns somthing that can be used as a density, being derived is long the lines of page 23, eqn 2.1.2, 2.1.3 [here](https://lib.dr.iastate.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=7505&context=etd)

My Question: How would I set this derivative up in MMA using `bsm` above?

Comment: Possibly the problems reported are due to problems in code you used but did not post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't evaluate with `At=K`, rather evaluate for some value of `At`, and then you have a density for the variable K.

I believe the correct setup is like this:

```
dcdkk = Assuming[\[Sigma] > 0 && K > 0 && \[Eta] > 0 && 
   q > 0 && \[Tau] > 0 && At > 0, FullSimplify[D[bsm, {K, 2}]]]

spdexp[K_] := (Exp[\[Eta]*\[Tau]]*dcdkk) //. {\[Tau] -> 
    1, \[Eta] -> 0.1, q -> 0.15, \[Sigma] -> 1.5, At -> 100}

dist = ProbabilityDistribution[spdexp[K], {K, 0, Infinity}]

CDF[dist][-\[Infinity]]

CDF[dist][\[Infinity]]

PDF[dist, K]

Plot[%, {K, 0, 12000}, Filling -> Axis]

CDF[dist, K]

Plot[%, {K, 0, 12000}, Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

Appreciate any answers that improve on the above.

Comment: Some notes: (1) There is an unclosed parenthesis in `spdexp`. (2) There is no `K` in the literal code for `spdexp`; consequently, no replacements will be done. Try `spdexp[7]` and you will see the unreplaced letter `K` (coming from value of `dcdkk`, which not evaluated until after *M* tries to replacement literally present `K`). (3) `K` is used internally by the system in various function. Using it as your own variable is a potential bug. (4) Indeed, the advice generally is to avoid starting your own variable and function names with a capital.

Comment: (1) Thanks. Fixed. The rest I'll check & correct when I get to a computer with MMA on it.